# NSMutableAttributedString not working: bold the part of NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring

Trying to bold the starting part of NSString. Using the code mentioned below.

```
-(void)setText {

    NSString *strEmail = @"Email: HR_Contact@sre.com";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedEmail = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:strEmail];
    NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont fontWithName:_fontMyriadBold size:20] fontName];
    NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 5);
    [attributedEmail beginEditing];
    [attributedEmail addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                   value:boldFontName
                   range:boldedRange];

    [attributedEmail endEditing];

    lblEmailAddress.attributedText = attributedEmail;
}
```

It doesn't make any change. Why so, what is the issue am not getting no warnings or errors.
Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: boldFontName need in fact to be a `UIFont`. The "Name" at the end, works for "AttributeName" in "one" word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this.

```
NSString * strEmail = @"Email: HR_Contact@sre.com";
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedEmail = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:strEmail];
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 5);
[attributedEmail addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:_fontMyriadBold size:20] range:boldedRange];
[attributedEmail addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [*UICOLOR*] range:boldedRange]; // if needed
[lblEmailAddress setAttributedText: attributedEmail];
```

Comment: This answers the question. I had a similar answer but, since this was posted first so, I had deleted it.

Comment: @Aavaarai I tried this but not working, i want to make you notice that the label is taken in xib file, does that matter because in coding i also think there is no issue.

Comment: even my code was right, the xib connection was broken. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting this attributed string? Maybe in one of the `-init`? Maybe `lblEmailAddress` is still nil at this point where are you trying to set it. If so, that is the reason why it doesn't work for you. If I understood correctly `lblEmailAddress` comes from *.xib.